# Avoid rerendering of FlatList row

Tags: android, ios, performance, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am using React Native FlatList to show data on the row. Following is my code.

HomeScreen.js

```
render() {

    return (
      <View
        style={styles.container}
        onLayout={this.onLayout.bind(this)}>
        <Spinner visible={this.state.isShowSpinner} animation="fade" color={APP_THEME_COLOR} />
        <View style={styles.subContainerStyle}>

          {facetWebView}

          <AnimatedFlatList
            style={styles.flatListStyle}
            ref={flatListRef => this.templateFlatList = flatListRef}
            data={this.state.templatePosts}
            renderItem={({item}) => this.renderCellItem(item)}
          />
         </View>
         </View>
   } 

  renderCellItem(item, index) {

    return (
      <TemplateCell
        item={item}
        index={index}
        isPortraitMode={this.state.isPortraitMode}
        didSelectItemFromCell={(item) => {
          this.didSelectItemFromCell(item)
        }}
      />
    )
  }
```

In the TemplateCell I am showing the favorite/unfavorite status. I wrote the shouldComponentUpdate in TemplateCell as

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {

    const isItemChanged = this.props.item != nextProps.item
    const isPortraitMode = this.props.isPortraitMode != nextProps.isPortraitMode
    return isItemChanged || isPortraitMode
}

But still it is rendering the cell again. How can I avoid this.
```

I found that in the link https://codeburst.io/when-to-use-component-or-purecomponent-a60cfad01a81

Never MUTATE
You’ve probably been hearing not to mutate objects and arrays in props and state. If you were to mutate objects in a parent component, your “pure” child components wouldn’t update. Although the values have changed upstream, the child would be comparing the reference to the previous props and not detect a difference.

I believe that my array is mutable thats why changes done item object is remains same in props and nextProps. How to avoid this

Comment: what if you set `keyExtractor` for your `FlatList`, like `keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.UNIQUE_PROP}`

Comment: @Cherniv  keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}

Comment: When does it render again, the cases?

Comment: @RaviRaj 1. When I clicking on button on row to change the favorite status
2. When I do load more for flat list
3. When I am showing some other UI in same screen

Answer (score 0):

Your array is not mutable. From what I understand when changes are made to it a new array is returned as it should. 
This is why checking by reference won't help you here. You need to check by some value in your item.

For example:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {

  const isItemChanged = this.props.item.status != nextProps.item.status
  const isPortraitMode = this.props.isPortraitMode != nextProps.isPortraitMode
  return isItemChanged || isPortraitMode
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually my Array is mutable. When I am checking this.props.item.status and nextProps.item.status, I always get same value for both.

Comment: Then maybe you have a different problem. The Flatlist is a Pure Component and if you want it to update even if the length of the array data doesn't change you should add the extraData prop as described in the documentation (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html#extradata). If your array doesn't change in length and only an item in the array changes one of it values your flatlist will not re render

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this will be the best answer, but I managed to solve this issue. I have used deepcopy library.

```
const newItem = deepcopy(item)
newItem.isFavorite = !item.isFavorite
const templates = this.state.templatePosts
var index = templates.indexOf(item)
templates.splice(index, 1, newItem);
this.setState({
  templatePosts: templates
})
```

Now, I am able to use

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {

    const isItemChanged = this.props.item != nextProps.item
    const isPortraitMode = this.props.isPortraitMode != nextProps.isPortraitMode
    return isItemChanged || isPortraitMode
}
```